# asp.Core Dependency injection

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection

I started migrating my MVC app to .Core from asp.Net 4.6. The application is quite big,40 controllers ~30 DAls/Reps..so I am trying to plan out what I need to refactor and how.
I got a couple of beginner questions.

I have a couple of DALs/Repositories which I inject into Controllers. But will I be able to use them within each other?

```
public class FirstRep(SecondRep secondRep){}
```

What if I (really) need to call above class ,from lets say a background task, with a parameter? Will framework inject the SecondRep for me, or do I need to initiate it manually?

```
public class FirstRep(SecondRep secondRep, int someId){}

public void NoopBackgroundTask(int someId){
    var firstRep = new FirstRep(someId);
 }
```

The application structure is more or less:

Controller -> BLL/Dal-> Background Tasks

For code reuse, some BLLs are using other BLLs.

Thank you

Comment: They seem to be a little iffy by themselves but you can always plug in another DI container (like the one you're using now). ASP.Core only provides a simple default.

Comment: Thank you for response. I only started digging into the DI concept couple days ago. Do you know any github projects where I could see real-life example of something similar to that I am trying to achieve at my second question? I been googling for a while now...